# How to store currency ranges in a Postgres table?

Tags: database, database-design, postgres

I am using Postgres 9.3.

I have to store range data like `<$250K, $250K-$4M,` etc which we will display in a dropdown.

now I am making a table for all possible options that can be configured from an admin interface.

Should I take separate column for min,max,currency_type(dollar,euro) and a column to store K,M etc or there is a better way to do that ?

Comment: Three columns: Start, End, CurrencyType. E.g. 0, 250, USD

Comment: just a suggestion:  do *not* store **K** or **M** (order of magnitude) in the database.  This is considered display/formatting logic and can be calculated on the fly.  I'd even go as far as saying it *should* be calculated on the fly because it is a more flexible approach.

Comment: @MetaFight: More importantly, you can't compare 5K to 4M. But you can compare 5000 and 4000000. So you can't do things like finding the overlaps in ranges. Of course, if you're not going to do all of that, you might as easily store the range as a display string.

Comment: I am using postgres datatype range. that should be fine right ?

Comment: What relevance does the `range` data type have here?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar just glancing at it, yes, storing the data as a native range type would not be a bad thing.  `[0,250000)` seems to be an elegant way of handling the data if you are working with the values as a range (is this in the range? what is the intersection of these ranges?). I would be sure to read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) throughly and be sure to play with it a bit to get an understanding before diving in to it head first as its not something that people who aren't familiar with it... are... well, familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you will be needing ranges for different kinds of dropdowns;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If these are intended to be *all-encompassing* ranges that all values must fall within, I'd just store either the maximum or minimum value of the range in a single column.

```
ID | Amount 
-----------
 1 |      0
 2 | 250000 
 3 | 500000 
 4 |1000000 
 5 |2000000
```

You can calculate the actual ranges on the fly from this.